# Adobe InDesign transfer form field data within a document

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, forms

I'm trying to find a solution to the following:

I have an interactive pdf form, created in InDesign CC and need to reuse a field form data again in the same document. In another words, what the user enters once needs to be used more times automatically.

Can someone help please?